Live action program featuring woman with a bubble wand?
I don't really remember much about the movie or show as I was very young and cannot remember if it was a show or a movie. 
What I could remember is that it was a live action program and this particular scene where a woman, standing on a grass field, would take out a yellow or gold bubble wand out of her shirt pocket and waves it in circles in the air as she then proceeds to blow a bubble. I also remember that she would look through the bubble wand like a monocle and (I'm not quite sure of this but) would be able to see things that weren't really there. 
I was roughly 5 years old or less. I was born in 1995 so it must be from any year below the 2000s.
The language was English, I'm sure of that. 
I hope this is enough as this is as much information I could provide.
(P.s. I know it must exist somewhere because I asked my mom about it and she remembers the same thing!)
